# Mac os x 10.5.8 Can't download Flash Player!

Tags: leopard, adobe-flash

I am having issues installing Adobe Flash Player on my 10.5.8 Mac. I uninstalled the previous version. My understanding understand is that i need an older version of flash player as this is an older Mac.

I've been to the archived flash player page and tried downloading several older versions. In each case, it starts to download, then after say 19% it says "Installation Failed". I've tried loads of times, and tried loads of different ways of doing it and i'm at a loss!!! Please Help!

Comment: Did you try the answer from here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1016650

Comment: Yes, it didn't really apply. It's saving, but then 5-19% into the install, it just says "install Failed". Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe if you visit they help here http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-mac.html#Flash_Player_for_Safari

Comment: For which browser ?

Comment: And how did you remove the previous version? was it a complete removal, no left overs ?

Comment: Try http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_10.3.183.90_archive_mac_only.zip [direct Adobe archive link, full installers not web] supports 10.5 (btw, you will still struggle with some new Flash sites, on that version)

Comment: Installing old versions of flash is like jumping naked into a vat of used needles - you're exposing yourself to extremely well known exploits of every kind

Answer (score 2):

The older version cannot be downloaded and installed because Apple bars such an operation.

Due to Malware and hacking reasons, Apple does not support the installation of this program.   Nobody knows of a way around it unless it is copied over from another Mac.